Is there a DC voltage on a transmitter power amplifier's output?
When studying the answers to Are my power calculations on this MOSFET Power Amplifier accurate? , I noticed this contradiction:

If you integrate V * A, you get average power of about 2 W
If you calculate Vrms and multiply it by A (or by Vrms/R), you get about 500 mW

I was very puzzled by this at first, until realizing that #1 includes DC power, which is purely lost as heat, whereas #2 is signal only.
Is that correct? If so, does this DC power cause any problems? Should it be eliminated? I tried capacitive coupling of the circuit to the load, but couldn't get this to work.
Furthermore, the entire circuit only uses about 1.4 W of power! So where does that extra 600 mW of V * A come from? I imagine it might have to do with reactive power sloshing back and forth, without using energy, but that can't be the full story, since a full 2 W must be dissipated in the load.



The amplifier is DC coupled to the load. Put a DC block (100nF) in front of the 50 Ohm load or the lowpass filter.

@Raonoke Thanks! I had tried something like that, but, since I wasn't calculating power correctly, thought it attenuated the signal.  Since a 100nF still has 227 Ω impedance, don't I need much more capacitance, so as not to throw off the 50 Ω load?

@SRobertJames A 100 nF capacitor has 227 ohm impedance at 6 kHz. Your schematic shows a source frequency of 7 MHz which means the impedance of a 100nF capacitor is close to 0.2 ohms. Perhaps you were using a 10 pF capacitor in your experiments.

@SRobertJames - Without DC block there is 0.12A DC current heating up the load. You probably overlooked the 1e-03 factor while calculating the reactance of the 100nF DC block @ 7MHz.

Got it! Thank you @qrk and Raonoke.  Still left to understand: Without the DC block, how did the load get 2W out of 1.4W power supply?

@SRobertJames - Output power > input power is understandably not possible. If we assume that the amplifier has a decent efficiency of 80% and puts out 1W RF with inserted DC block then it draws ~0.209A from the 6V supply. Without DC block the drawn DC current increases by another 0.12A (6V/50Ohm) which makes the total DC input power 1.975W while the power (DC + RF) in the 50 Ohm load is now 1.72W.

The waveform in the graph does not have an average of 2 watts. Are you getting to nice places with micro-cap yet?
